# Overwrite og meta details by values in parameters for social sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I am using following kind of URL for facebook sharing:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://sharethingz.com&t=%22my%20title%22&summary=%22Here%20is%20my%20summary%22
```

Facebook is scrapping data from my page i.e. og meta. I want to add all the data by myself using parameters in URL.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the parameters with `sharer.php`, you should instead use [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog). Its quite simple to integrate it.

You can use the URL Redirection:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id={app-id}
  &display=popup
  &caption={caption}
  &link={link}
  &title={title}
  &picture={picture}
  &description={description}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-url}
```

You can find the list of parameters [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params).